# Sort from low to high using wordpress review widget

Tags: arrays, wordpress, sorting

Need some help getting widget to sort the reviews from low to high. I know this is reverse of the norm, but this website focuses on how "bad" something is. The website is here: http://designtatics.fatcow.com/Badkickstarter/ it's the second tab down called top 3. Excuse the mess, still a work in progress.

```
            // order by rating?
    if (isset($order) && $order == 'rating') {

    $query_args['orderby'] = 'meta_value';
            }
    else {
        $query_args['orderby'] = 'date';
    }

    $r = new WP_Query($query_args);
```

I've already tried adding $query_args['order'] = 'ASC'; with no luck. This is all new to me so the more specific the better. Thanks!

UPDATE: I think I was trying to modify the wrong widget, heres the new code:

```
    <?php

class Bunyad_TabbedRecent_Widget extends WP_Widget
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct(
            'bunyad-tabbed-recent-widget',
            'Bunyad - Recent Tabs',
            array('description' => __('Tabs: Recent, category1, category2...', 'bunyad-widgets'), 'classname' => 'tabbed')
        );

        add_action('save_post', array($this, 'flush_widget_cache'));
        add_action('deleted_post', array($this, 'flush_widget_cache'));
        add_action('switch_theme', array($this, 'flush_widget_cache'));

        // init hook
        add_action('init', array($this, 'init'));

    }

    public function init() 
    {
        // only in admin cp for form
        if (is_admin()) {
            wp_enqueue_script('widget-tabs', plugins_url('/bunyad-widgets/js/widget-tabs.js'));
        }
    }

    // @todo wrap existing widgets with in-memory cache
    public function widget($args, $instance) 
    {
        global $post; // setup_postdata not enough

        // set defaults
        $titles = $cats = $tax_tags = array();

        extract($args);
        extract($instance);

        // missing data?
        if (!count($titles) OR !count($cats)) {
            _e('Recent tabs widget still need to be configured! Add tabs, add a title, and select type for each tab in widgets area.', 'bunyad-widgets');
            return; 
        }

        $tabs = array();
        foreach ($titles as $key => $title) {

            // defaults missing?
            if (empty($tax_tags[$key])) {
                $tax_tags[$key] = '';
            }

            if (empty($cats[$key])) {
                $cats[$key] = '';
            }

            $tabs[$title] = array('cat_type' => $cats[$key], 'tag' => $tax_tags[$key]);
        }

        // latest posts
        $posts = $this->get_posts($tabs, $number);

        ?>

        <?php echo $before_widget; ?>

        <ul class="tabs-list">

            <?php
            $count = 0; 
            foreach ($posts as $key => $val): $count++; $active = ($count == 1 ? 'active' : ''); 
            ?>

            <li class="<?php echo $active;?>">
                <a href="#" data-tab="<?php echo esc_attr($count); ?>"><?php echo $key; ?></a>
            </li>

            <?php endforeach; ?>

        </ul>

        <div class="tabs-data">
            <?php
                $i = 0; 
                foreach ($posts as $tab => $tab_posts): $i++; $active = ($i == 1 ? 'active' : ''); ?>

            <ul class="tab-posts <?php echo $active; ?> posts-list" id="recent-tab-<?php echo esc_attr($i); ?>">

            <?php if ($tabs[$tab] == 'comments'): ?>

                <?php 
                foreach ($tab_posts as $comment): 
                ?>

                <li class="comment">

                    <span class="author"><?php printf('%s said', get_comment_author_link($comment->comment_ID)); ?></span>

                    <p class="text"><?php comment_excerpt($comment->comment_ID); ?></p>

                    <a href=""><?php echo get_the_title($comment->comment_post_ID); ?></a>

                </li>

                <?php               
                endforeach; 
                ?>


            <?php else: ?>

                <?php foreach ($tab_posts as $post): setup_postdata($post); ?>

                <li>

                    <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail('post-thumbnail', array('title' => strip_tags(get_the_title()))); ?>

                    <?php if (class_exists('Bunyad') && Bunyad::options()->review_show_widgets): ?>
                        <?php echo apply_filters('bunyad_review_main_snippet', ''); ?>
                    <?php endif; ?>

                    </a>

                    <div class="content">

                        <time datetime="<?php echo get_the_date('Y-m-d\TH:i:sP'); ?>"><?php echo get_the_date(); ?> </time>

                        <span class="comments"><a href="<?php echo esc_attr(get_comments_link()); ?>"><i class="fa fa-comments-o"></i>
                            <?php echo get_comments_number(); ?></a></span>

                        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php echo esc_attr(get_the_title() ? get_the_title() : get_the_ID()); ?>">
                            <?php if (get_the_title()) the_title(); else the_ID(); ?></a>

                    </div>

                </li>

                <?php endforeach; ?>

            <?php endif; ?>

            </ul>
            <?php endforeach; ?>

        </div>

        <?php echo $after_widget; ?>

        <?php

        wp_reset_postdata();

    }

    public function get_posts($tabs, $number)
    {
        // posts available in cache? - use instance id to suffix
        $cache = get_transient('bunyad_tabbed_recent_posts');

        if (is_array($cache) && isset($cache[$this->number])) {
            return $cache[$this->number];
        }

        // get posts
        $args = array('numberposts' => $number, 'ignore_sticky_posts' => 1);
        foreach ($tabs as $key => $val) {   

            $opts = array();

            switch ($val['cat_type']) {
                case 'popular':
                    $opts['orderby'] = 'comment_count';
                    break;

                case 'comments':
                    $posts[$key] = get_comments(array('number'=> $number, 'status' => 'approve'));
                    continue 2; // jump switch and foreach loop

                case 'top-reviews':
                    // get top rated of all time
                    $opts = array_merge($opts, array('orderby' => 'meta_value', 'meta_key' => '_bunyad_review_overall'));
                    break;

                case 'recent':
                    break;

                case 'tag':
                    $opts['tag'] = $val['tag'];
                    break;

                default:
                    $opts['cat'] = intval($val['cat_type']);
                    break;
            }

            //$query = new WP_Query(array_merge($args, $opts));
            $posts[$key] = get_posts(array_merge($args, $opts));
        }

        if (!is_array($cache)) {
            $cache = array();
        }

        $cache[ $this->number ] = $posts;

        set_transient('bunyad_tabbed_recent_posts', $cache, 60*60*24*30); // 30 days transient cache

        return $posts;
    }

    public function flush_widget_cache()
    {
        delete_transient('bunyad_tabbed_recent_posts');
    }

    public function update($new, $old)
    {
        // fix categories
        foreach ($new['cats'] as $key => $cat) {
            $new['cats'][$key] = strip_tags($cat);
        }

        foreach ($new['titles'] as $key => $title) {
            $new['titles'][$key] = strip_tags($title);
        }

        foreach ($new['tax_tags'] as $key => $tag) {
            $new['tax_tags'][$key] = trim(strip_tags($tag));
        }

        $new['number'] = intval($new['number']);

        // delete cache
        $this->flush_widget_cache();

        return $new;
    }

    public function form($instance)
    {
        $instance = array_merge(array('titles' => array(), 'cats' => array(0), 'number' => 4, 'cat' => 0, 'tax_tags' => array()), $instance);

        extract($instance);

    ?>

        <style>
            .widget-content p.separator { padding-top: 10px; border-top: 1px solid #d8d8d8; }
            .widget-content .tax_tag { display: none; }
        </style>


        <div id="tab-options">


        <script type="text/html" class="template-tab-options">
        <p class="title separator">
            <label><?php printf(__('Tab #%s Title:', 'bunyad-widgets'), '<span>%n%</span>'); ?></label>
            <input class="widefat" name="<?php 
                echo esc_attr($this->get_field_name('titles')); ?>[%n%]" type="text" value="%title%" />
        </p>


        <div class="cat">
            <label><?php printf(__('Tab #%s Category:', 'bunyad-widgets'), '<span>%n%</span>'); ?></label>
            <?php 

            $r = array('orderby' => 'name', 'hierarchical' => 1, 'selected' => $cat, 'show_count' => 0);

            // categories list
            $cats_list = walk_category_dropdown_tree(get_terms('category', $r), 0, $r);

            // custom options
            $options = array(
                'recent' => __('Recent Posts', 'bunyad-widgets'), 
                'popular' => __('Popular Posts', 'bunyad-widgets'), 
                'top-reviews' => __('Top Reviews', 'bunyad-widgets'),
                'tag' => __('Use a Tag', 'bunyad-widgets'),
            );

            ?>

            <select name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('cats') .'[%n%]'; ?>">

            <?php foreach ($options as $key => $val): ?>

                <option value="<?php echo esc_attr($key); ?>"<?php echo ($cat == $key ? ' selected' : ''); ?>><?php echo esc_html($val); ?></option>            

            <?php endforeach; ?>

                <optgroup label="<?php _e('Category', 'bunyad-widgets'); ?>">
                    <?php echo $cats_list; ?>
                </optgroup>

            </select>

            <div class="tax_tag">
                <p><label><?php printf(__('Tab #%s Tag:', 'bunyad-widgets'), '<span>%n%</span>'); ?></label> <input type="text" name="<?php 
                    echo esc_attr($this->get_field_name('tax_tags')); ?>[%n%]" value="%tax_tag%" /></p>
            </div>

            <p><a href="#" class="remove-recent-tab">[x] <?php _e('remove', 'bunyad-widgets'); ?></a></p>
        </div>
        </script>


            <p class="separator"><a href="#" id="add-more-tabs"><?php _e('Add More Tabs', 'bunyad-widgets'); ?></a></p>

            <?php

            if (is_integer($this->number)): // create for valid instances only 

                foreach ($cats as $n => $cat):
            ?>

                <script>
                    jQuery(function($) {

                        $('.widget-liquid-right [id$="bunyad-tabbed-recent-widget-'+ <?php echo $this->number; ?> +'"] #add-more-tabs').trigger(
                                'click', 
                                [{
                                    'n': <?php echo ($n+1); ?>, 
                                    'title': '<?php echo esc_attr($titles[$n]); ?>', 
                                    'selected': '<?php echo esc_attr($cat); ?>',
                                    'tax_tag': '<?php echo esc_attr($tax_tags[$n]); ?>'
                                }]);
                    });
                </script>

            <?php
                endforeach; 
            endif; 
            ?>

        </div>

        <p><label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('number'); ?>"><?php _e('Number of posts in each tab:', 'bunyad-widgets'); ?></label>
        <input id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('number'); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('number'); ?>" type="text" value="<?php echo $number; ?>" size="3" />
        </p>


    <?php
    }

}
```

Comment: Have you considered using meta_value_num instead of meta_value to order in ASC manner?

Comment: I tried it, but It did not seem to make a difference.I feel as I am missing something

Comment: the current code snippets does not really show what is necessary to identify the widget or the code.  If you have already added 'order' => 'ASC' then there is something else we are not seeing in your code.

Comment: Robert, first thank you so much for the help. Do you want me to copy the entire widget script and paste it here? I would love to figure it out. And yes I tried exactly what you said: $opts = array_merge($opts, array('orderby' => 'meta_value', 'order' => 'ASC', 'meta_key' => '_bunyad_review_overall');     I also tried with meta_value_num

Comment: Yes I would suggest either putting the whole script in your post or putting it in a pastebin or something since you are unable to change the order or your meta_value.

Comment: @RobertLee, ok I put up the script for the entire widget. Sorry I did not go it sooner, I was doing some work around the house yesterday.